# How do I initiate my each loop only after I have click my submit button in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I have a Rails app that searches through a DB and returns items. At the moment in my view it automatically returns the default search results ("") without me needing to hit my submit_tag. How do I go about only making this action happen once I have hit the submit_tag? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my view:

```
 <%= form_tag(new_design_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Search all designs:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
  <% end %><br>
  <!-- Button to return one random design --> 
  <%= form_tag(new_design_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Inspire me! Click here for a random design:") %>
    <%= submit_tag("Random Design") %>
  <% end %>

  <h2>Search results:</h2>

  <% @random.each do |design| %>  
    <h3><%= design['name'] %></h3>
    <h5><%= image_tag design['thumbnail_url'] %></h5>
  <% end %>

  <% @search.each do |design| %>  
  <div class="design">
    <h3 class="design_name"><%= design['name'] %></h3>
    <h5><%= image_tag design['thumbnail_url'] %></h5>
    <%= button_to 'Save to Favourites',
      designs_path(
        design: design.slice('name', 'thumbnail_url') 
      ),method: :post %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

And my controller:

```
class DesignsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @designs = Design.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
        # returns an array of hashes
        @search = SpoonflowerApi.new.find(params[:q])['results']
        @random = SpoonflowerApi.new.random(rand(1..740579), 1)['results']
    end

    def create
    @design = Design.new(design_params)
    @design.save
        if @design.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Design has been added to favourites!'
        else
            flash[:notice] = 'Design already in Favourites!'
    end
    redirect_to new_design_path
  end

  def destroy
    @design = Design.find(params[:id])
    @design.destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'Design removed from favourites!'
    redirect_to designs_path
  end

  private

  def design_params
    params.require(:design).permit(:name, :thumbnail_url) 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`new` is used to populate the initial form, so if you don't want anything for those fields you should just set both `@search` and `@random` to an empty array in new.  You don't show any code for your model, so it's not really clear what Api is.

`show` should be called once you submit the form

```
def new
  @search = []
  @random = []
end
```

then move the logic to provide the search results or random record into the show method

```
def show
  # not sure what you want to do here
  # since it seems like you have 2 buttons you need logic to provide data 
  # based on the button 
  # maybe something like this
  if params[:q].nil?
    @search = []
    @random = Api.new.random(rand(1..740579), 1)['results']
  else
    @search = Api.new.find(params[:q])['results']
    @random = []
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your view showing some search results before you click the search button.

Since you directly send the params[:q] to SpoonflowerApi, I am guessing that it returns some default value and your view draw it.

Simply update your controller to:

```
def new
    @search=[]

    @search = SpoonflowerApi.new.find(params[:q])['results'] unless params[:q].nil?
    @random = SpoonflowerApi.new.random(rand(1..740579), 1)['results']
end
```

Comment: Actually, that results in the random search design still showing up (both before searching and after searching)

Comment: This works for the `@search` part of the view but not for the `@random` part. Any ideas?

Comment: Simply do the same for the random, create an empty @random array at the top and add the same condition "unless params[:q].nil?" to query row.